# $variable = $_POST['images'] holds multiple imagelocations, how to grab the images?

Tags: php

im pretty new to PHP scripting, and i couldnt find the answer to my desires yet, so i was hoping someone could tell me how to do this.

Im getting a $_POST request to a php file, containing some data

```
stock_nr=1&manufacturer=Audi&model=A1&images=http%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081049%2F6911582-1-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081072%2F6911582-2-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081102%2F6911582-3-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081131%2F6911582-4-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081161%2F6911582-5-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081192%2F6911582-6-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081227%2F6911582-7-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081255%2F6911582-8-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081280%2F6911582-9-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081313%2F6911582-10-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081341%2F6911582-11-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081368%2F6911582-12-2-2.jpg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fimages0.wheeler.nl%2Fs1386081398%2F6911582-13-2-2.jpg
```

I have made a file to declare variables like this:

```
$stock_nr=$_POST['stock_nr'] ;
$manufacturer=$_POST['manufacturer'] ;
$model=$_POST['model'] ;
$images=$_POST['images'] ;
```

How can i get the amount of imagelinks which are posted in a variable?

Edit: This is what i wanted to do, and it works fine.

This is what i wanted to do, and it does what it should do:

```
function process_images() {
        $images = explode(',', $_POST['images']);
        foreach($images as $image_nr => $image_url) {
            $filename = 'images/'. $_POST['stock_nr'] .'-'. $image_nr .'.jpg';

            $imgdata = file_get_contents($image_url);
            file_put_contents($filename, $imgdata);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links are separated by "," you just need to [explode()](http://php.net/explode) it.

```
$images=explode(',',$_POST['images']);
print_r($images);
```

Comment: Ah yah, how stupid of me...
[code] function process_images() {
  $images = explode(',', $_POST['images']);
  foreach($images as $image_nr => $image_url) {
   $filename = 'images/'. $_POST['stock_nr'] .'-'. $image_nr .'.jpg';
   
   $imgdata = file_get_contents($image_url);
   file_put_contents($filename, $imgdata);
  }
 }[/code]

Comment: if you find this answer correct please mark is as the answer with mark sign :) thanks.